# How to assign a value to a casted column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am wondering whether is possible to assign a value to a casted column in SQL depending on real table values.

For Example:

```
 select *, cast(null as number) as value from table1
 where if(table1.id > 10 then value = 1) else value = 0
```

NOTE: I understand the above example is not completely Oracle, but, it is just a demonstration on what I want to accomplish in Oracle. Also, the above example can be done multiple ways due to its simplicity. My goal here is to verify if it is possible to accomplish the example using casted columns (columns not part of table1) and some sort of if/else.

Thanks,
Y_Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select table1.*, (case when table1.id > 10 then 1 else 0 end) as value
from table1
```

Comment: +1 but just a minor quibble the parens around the case aren't required

Comment: I had a basic idea that it was close to the 'case' keyword. Thank for completing the idea.